# Do i need to change database configuration in database.php file in laravel when upload to server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, web-hosting, shared-hosting

> Do i need to change database configuration in database.php file in laravel when upload to server?

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: Update with server site database name, password and other details

Comment: it is already set in .env file .Need to chagne it here also? what is forge?

Comment: Yes.. forge is just example, update this with your database name and root

Answer (score 4):

Don't change anything in `database.php` config file. What you need to do is to change DB credentials in `.env` file on server side.

So, you'll have different `.env` files on a local machine and server, but the same `database.php` config file.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Update your database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'yourdatabasename'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```